# How to print shapes on A4 paper in a certain co-ordinates in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i want to print some shapes(circles, rectangles) with exact size to certain coordinates on A4 paper. I use c#, winform. So what is your advice for this operation.
**EDIT**
OK, let me explain my question..
We have a school, and every month we make exams to our student, for exam we use answer sheets like in pictures below.
[image: simple section from answer sheet]

and in during exam students fill circles about their school information like name, surname, class, group and etc.
We want to simplify this process before exam. we want to print student informations to the answer sheet. Our program must get information from database and print(draw small circles to appropriate cells) on the answer sheet. And i have to print exactly to coordinates if circles. Otherwise it will have mistakes.
Answer sheet in A4 form.
That's it my question.
Thank you..

Comment: i cant understand downvotes.......

Comment: I downvoted because you haven't tried anything so far and appear to want us to write your code for you with very little information to go on...

Comment: please explain you downvotes, i am serious in this question....

Comment: Read your edit - still not shown what you've tried so far. Have you tried writing any code to do this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Graphics of a bitmap to draw the shapes, then save the image and print it manually with page preview.